# tar commands returns stdin error

Tags: 12.04, backup, tar

```
tar -xvfz files.tgz
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

This the error i got.
(This file is created by `tar -cvzf file.tgz file` )
Moreover i can able to extract this same in another ubuntu server. I'm using AWS ec2 server. 
please someone help

Comment: The fun is that, i created a .tgz file using in that sever, and i could extract it without any error message.

Comment: You can [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/505945/edit) your question. Look for the grey edit link right below the list of tags.

Answer (score 4):

Watch the ordering. The `-f` option represents the file, and it should be immediately followed by the file name. The proper command here is `tar -xvzf files.tgz`.

Comment: i tried that format, but result is same. i have also tried unp command, which returns same error.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists, and that the file is actually gzip-compressed data? Run `file files.tgz` to verify that the output says (at least) `gzip compressed data`. Also, check the file sizes on the server and your computer.

Comment: same issue here but my file type is `DOS executable (COM)` instead of `gzip compressed data`. What does this mean ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a `tar` file. Just rename the file or directory like `files.tar`

and then do `tar -xvzf files.tar`.

It will do the trick. I also faced the same error and resolved it on AWS.